# How to summarize numbers entered by user?

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment and have most of what i think will work down, i have to promt the user for random numbers, then display how many negatives as well as positives then sum and average, can anyone help me as i cannot get my code to display the correct amount of values for negative or positive or get it to sum. Here is what i have so far( i also added the break in the end , otherwise it went to an infinate loop)

```
//Random number evaluation
package chapter_4;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Four_One {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int positive = 0;
       int negative = 0;
       int sum = 0;
       int count = 0;

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter in a value, if 0 is entered program stops: ");
       int data = input.nextInt();


       while (data != 0) {
            sum += data;

            if (data < 0)
               negative++;

            else if (data > 0)
               positive++;

           count++;

        System.out.println("The number of positives is: " + positive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is:" + negative);
        System.out.println("The total is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / data); 

        break; }

       }   

}
```

Comment: What's the loop supposed to do in your opinion?

Comment: what are you having problem with?

Comment: In Java, *never* use the break keyword. Only one exception: always use it in switch blocks. Break & continue are very very bad words for java programs. And there will always be a cleaner alternative.

Comment: In this case, you should assign data = input.nextInt inside your loop...

Comment: @Snicolas: You say "never" but it really a stylistic and comfortability issue.  I can read and debug code just fine that uses break, but I do avoid writing such code (mostly because I prefer smooth execution blocks for readability/understandability, and try to keep my loops very small, or extract large blocks of code to methods).  Break isn't as heinous as an actual goto.  That being said, it doesn't really belong in this block at all :)  An `if` would make more sense (if it really isn't supposed to loop)

Comment: I completely disagree, but having said my word here is enough and better than arguing. Break ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. You are not asking for the `nextInt()` within the `while` loop - you do want to ask more than once, correct?
2. Your average is not an average. I suggest dividing by count instead of data.

Comment: The program only needs to ask once, then once the user hits enter or zero the program executes and displays the total +numbers, -numbers as well as the total

Comment: @user823119: Your are misunderstanding "ask once" - the prompt can be displayed once, but right now you are only reading input *once*.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks! I am sorry as I know this is simple but it is really stumping me!

Comment: It works now! I had no idea i would have to ask inside and outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

at the end of the loop (instead of the break) add `data = input.nextInt();`

btw for average you should display `sum/(double)count` (the cast to double is there so you'll see the fraction)

Comment: Ok thank you , just didn't know how to stop the infinite loop

Comment: @user because you didn't read the next number the user entered and just kept going with the first as if it was the next one

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.
Explanation: Using a do-while loop might be easier because it asks for input and than checks the input. Also put the input statement inside the do-While loop so it asks for multiple inputs.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   int positive = 0;
   int negative = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   int count = 0;
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int data = 0;
   do
   {
       System.out.print("Enter in a value, if 0 is entered program stops: ");
       data = input.nextInt();

       sum += data;
       count ++;

       if(data < 0)
           negative ++;
       else if(data > 0)
           positive ++;
    }
    //Stops if the value of data is ZERO(0) and continues if it's not
    while(data != 0);

    System.out.println("Positive Numbers = " + positive);
    System.out.println("Negative Numbers = " + negative);
    System.out.println("Sum of Numbers = " + sum);
    System.out.println("Total Numbers = " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Four_One {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int positive = 0;
        int negative = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter in a value, if 0 is entered program stops: ");

        int data = input.nextInt();

        while (data != 0) {
            sum += data;

            if (data < 0)
                negative++;

            else if (data > 0)
                positive++;

            count++;
            data = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("The number of positives is: " + positive);
        System.out.println("The number of negatives is:" + negative);
        System.out.println("The total is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / (double)count);
    }

}
```

Comment: hmm i actually just saw that the average has to be a floating point number rather a double?

Comment: replace _double_ with _float_: System.out.println("The average is: " + sum / (float)count);